# Convention for camel cased identifier with "iPhone" or "iPad" in the name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, naming-conventions

TRiViAL, I know, but is there a convention for the "i" in an iDevice name, as part of a longer identifier, when sticking to the `camelCase` convention? Does Apple have any method names or identifiers as examples of such?

`someIPadMethod` vs. `someiPadMethod`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one for you: `kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ`

And here's another that uses the opposite convention: `kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel`

And a third kind: `NSCoreDataVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_4_0`

Looks like multiple conventions.